# In which version of "@solana/spl-token" the "getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount" method is available

Tags: web3.js, spl-token

I want to transfer the spl token but cannot get getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount method even in the latest version of @solana/spl-token.

Comment: Could you provide a picture of your code / error?

Comment: showing us the code would be the first step to solving this issue.

Comment: I am getting this error 
Module '"@solana/spl-token"' has no exported member 'getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount'.

Comment: I which version of "@solana/spl-token"' the 'getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount' is available ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing @solana/spl-token with an alias name, there might be another dependency that's causing a naming conflict.

```
npm i name-it-what-you-want-here@npm:@solana/spl-token
```

It will look like this in `package.json`

```
  "dependencies": {
    "name-it-what-you-want-here": "npm:@solana/spl-token@^0.3.6"
  }
```

Then import with alias name to use

```
import { getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount } from "name-it-what-you-want-here"
```